# Dataprovider for gridview with selected data

Tags: gridview, yii, yii2, dataprovider

i want a gridview dataprovider with selected value in database 
data to be select:

```
$query = hotel::findAll(['supplier_name'=> $params]);
```

please help me to design dataprovider for gridview

Answer (score 1):

In yii2  for dataProvider  you should use find()->where

```
$query = Hotel::find()->where(['supplier_name'=> $params]);
```

and eventually for models

```
$models= Hotel::find()->where(['supplier_name'=> $params])->all();
```

Comment: can u please provide me full description of dataprovider function. i am new in yii

Comment: @ParitoshMahale   guide http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html   reference http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-activedataprovider.html

Comment: i have done with creating dataprovider but it showing me error message "Getting unknown property: yii\data\ActiveDataProvider::ID" i am not getting the reson

Comment: @ParitoshMahale   Update your question and    Show me your Hotel  model  code please